# How can I get mongo mapper to generate the config/mongo.yml file in Rails 4

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongomapper

I am trying to make a rails app using the Mongo Mapper gem.  I am following the instructions in the Mongo Mapper Documentation.

Here is the link: [Mongo Mapper Docs](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html)

First, I generated a new rails 4 app excluding activerecord.

```
rails new my_app --skip-active-record
```

In the next step I added the gem 'mongo_mapper' and gem 'bson_ext' and then bundled.

The next step is generating the config/mongo.yml file.

When I try to run the command:

```
script/rails generate mongo_mapper:config
```

I get this error:

`Could not find generator mongo_mapper:config.`

There is currently  no information on installing Mongo Mapper with Rails 4 and I am not sure if I am missing something that changed from Rails 3 to 4.

How can I get mongo mapper to generate the config/mongo.yml file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to change my Gemfile to use a beta version of the Mongo Mapper gem to add support for Rails 4.  Here is the updated Gemfile.

```
gem 'mongo_mapper', :git => "git://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper.git", :tag => "v0.13.0.beta2"
```

Comment: This piece of code work just well. It fixed the error and the configuration file is generated by the command suggested in mongo mapper documentation.