# rails-api not allowing any generation

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper, rails-api

I'm struggling trying to get the configuration of rails-api with the mongo_mapper gem.

I'm using rails v 4.1.1

gemfile looks as follows

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongo_mapper', :git => "git://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper.git", :tag => "v0.13.0.beta2"
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'railties'
```

I ran `rails-api new test-app --skip-active-record` which generates a simple file structure.

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.rdoc
├── Rakefile
└── config.ru
```

After that, per the instructions on the README for mongo_mapper I specified the correct version in my gemfile so that it's compatible with Rails 4.

```
gem 'mongo_mapper', :git => "git://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper.git", :tag => "v0.13.0.beta2"
```

According to 
- http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html 
- [How can I get mongo mapper to generate the config/mongo.yml file in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879866/how-can-i-get-mongo-mapper-to-generate-the-config-mongo-yml-file-in-rails-4)

I should then be able to run `bundle exec rails generate mongo_mapper:config`. It was here I started running into issues.

I first realized I need railsties gem since it wasn't even letting me run rails generate.

```
$ bundle exec rails generate mongo_mapper:config
/Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:248:in `block in replace_gem': railties is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

After adding that gem it allowed me to run `bundle exec rails generate mongo_mapper:config` but doesn't actually have access to that mongo generator. The output from the command is the standard rails help info including usage, options etc.

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
```

#### What I've tried so far

- I've tried building out what the generator is supposed to build as is described in this guide

http://technicaldebt.com/getting-started-with-ruby/mongomapper-ith-rails-quickstart/

But then realized that even if I build that out there's obviously still some "glue" that I'm missing, which ties everything together. I built it out just in case and of course it still didn't work.

- I've made sure to bundle and and reload the terminal appropriately.

Like I said, I'm pretty sure there's something necessary that gets skipped when I build the rails-api without active record.

Any thoughts on this? Would greatly appreciate the help.

For what it's worth this is the full output when I ran rails-api new my_app --skip-active-record.

```
$ rails-api new pitfworld_wide_atrocities_db --skip-active-record
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
(erb):19:in `template': undefined method `name' for []:Array (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/erb.rb:850:in `eval'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/erb.rb:850:in `result'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `block in template'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:53:in `call'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:53:in `render'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in invoke!'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `open'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `block in invoke!'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `call'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:25:in `create_file'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:115:in `template'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:17:in `template'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:45:in `gemfile'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:133:in `build'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:176:in `create_root_files'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-api-0.2.1/bin/rails-api:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rails-api:23:in `load'
    from /Users/colinhhart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rails-api:23:in `<main>'
```

## Solution

I came across that rails-api issue right as I was writing this post and it turned out that that was the issue, after banging my head forever thinking it was a mongo issue.

The issue has been fixed and closed but hasn't yet been released and will probably be released in rails-api v0.2.2.

Ultimately, I decided to just go into the rails-api source code and apply the changes locally.

Comment: I still don't have enough rep to post other links sighh..

The error in the trace above is seemingly resolved here [link](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/issues/142)

Comment: As I have pursued the rails-api generation error I'm almost convinced that might end up being the issue. Interestingly I'm running the latest version of the gem and so should have the updated source code that fixed this problem.